# Not able to push() the elements(after first iteration) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string and one array I am not able to push the elements after the first iteration not able to push the elements. I am using the Following Code.

```
response1 = "hello";
var arr = [""];

arr.push(response1);
console.log("First position " + arr[0]);
console.log("Second position " + arr[1]);
console.log("Third position " + arr[2]);
```

on the third iteration getting undefined like following.

```
First position 
Second position hello
Third position undefined
```

Comment: What do you expect to get instead of `undefined`?

Comment: where is the loop?

Comment: I can't see any loop in your code..

Comment: hello, should push after each iteration. check it out here. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_push

Comment: The code is working exactly as it should. You push `hello` to the array which it logs and then you push nothing so `arr[2]` will return undefined.

Comment: There is no iteration and your `arr` contains an empty string at first/0 position  and hello at second/1.

Comment: put whole code here not just some part.

Comment: What do you expect instead of `undefined`?

Comment: You are only pushing to the array once, look more closely to the code in the link you shared, there is a button which on click calls a function which pushes to the array. So if you click 5 times, 5 elements will be pushed. But in your code, you are only pushing to the array once.

Comment: Yes, I got, I will put var arr = [""]; outside of the function then I will get.

Comment: Probably, your push Is pushing value in position 1 because before push the Array length is 1. Share the relevant code because the problem Is before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really `pushed` anything onto the 2nd index of the array, and hence you get `undefined`. Nothing surprising. I suggest that you should learn the basics of the language first. It seems you have some misunderstandings.

Comment: @Samson Also, please don't take my suggestion as offensive or insulting. I truly and sincerely believe that it will help you.

Comment: No Bro, Everything should be in a positive way. Good Day.